# How to force close a readable stream?

Tags: node.js, nodes

I need force close a readline file... IN LINE 11! I need optimization!! But not workd the call `this.emit("close");`[image]

```
var readline = require('readline');
    var stream = require('stream');
    function get_line3(filename, number, callback) {
        var instream = fs.createReadStream(filename);
        var outstream = new stream;
        var rl = readline.createInterface(instream, outstream);
        var contp = 0;
        var data = "";

        rl.on("line", function(line) {
            console.log(contp);
            if (contp==number) this.emit("pause", line);
            contp++;        
        });

        rl.on("pause", function(line) {
            // do some work here
            console.log("doing some work");
            console.log(line);
            data = line;
            this.emit("resume");
        }); 

        rl.on("resume", function(line) { 
            this.emit("close"); // NOT WORK !!!
        });

        rl.on("close", function() {
            // do something on finish here
            callback(null, data);   
        });
    }
```

Comment: what makes you think this would be more "optimized"?  it may be more efficient to read in a block of data even if it's more than 11 lines.

Comment: @Joe I want to find a certain line and modify it, this I got! But after finding it I do not have to keep scanning the file until the end. And, the number of line is dynamically, 11 or 1100..

Comment: @Joe It would be more efficient if I went to a direct line. No need to scan the file ... Is there something like this?